# Doxygen require some additional commands

Tags: jenkins, doxygen

I am building a pipeline with Jenkins which also includes building the Doxygen documentation of my C/C++ library.

Doxygen automatically warns when a parameter of a method is not documented.

```
/**
 * @brief The brief of foo
 *
 */
void foo(int i)
{
}
```

This will generate the warning like:

```
error: The following parameters of foo(int i) are not documented: parameter 'i'
```

Can I easily add a test for other fields I require per file? Can Doxygen then generate a warning if it is not included?

Take the following as example:

Every file should include the **same** header like this:

```
/**
 * @file        foo.cpp
 * @brief       The brief
 * @copyright   Copyright [2020-2021] The Company
 * @authors     the author
 * @date        2021-09-27
 */
```

If Doxygen is run and one of the commands/fields is missing Doxygen should generate a warning like:

```
Required command @file is missing!
```

Can I configure Doxygen like this?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? No this is not possible in doxygen.

Comment: I'm using doxygen Version 1.9.1.